# Creating sequence indicators corresponding to data timing in R

Tags: r, time-series, data-manipulation, data-management

I am working with data that looks like this:

```
   ID Year Variable_of_Interest
1   a 2000                    0
2   a 2001                    0
3   a 2002                    0
4   a 2003                    0
5   a 2004                    0
6   a 2005                    1
7   a 2006                    1
8   a 2007                    1
9   a 2008                    1
10  a 2009                    1
11  b 2000                    0
12  b 2001                    0
13  b 2002                    0
14  b 2003                    1
15  b 2004                    1
16  b 2005                    1
17  b 2006                    0
18  b 2007                    1
19  b 2008                    1
20  b 2009                    1
21  c 2000                    0
22  c 2001                    0
23  c 2002                    0
24  c 2003                    0
25  c 2004                    0
26  c 2005                    0
27  c 2006                    1
28  c 2007                    1
29  c 2008                    1
30  c 2009                    0
31  d 2000                    0
32  d 2001                    0
33  d 2002                    1
34  d 2003                    1
35  d 2004                    0
36  d 2005                    1
37  d 2006                    1
38  d 2007                    1
39  d 2008                    1
40  d 2009                    1
```

The unit of analysis is in the `ID` column. The IDs repeat across each year in the data.

The `variable of interest` column represents changes to the IDs, wherein some years the values are a 0 and other years they are a 1.

I want to create an additional column that includes sequences of numbers that document the time before and after a code changes (defined as going from 0 to 1) in the `Variable_of_Interest` at the year before and after the change.

The code must account for repeat code changes (defined as going from 0 to 1), such as ID b from 2002-2003 and 2006-2007.

NAs can be assigned to 0 values without changes back to 1, such as 0 in "c" 2009.

Such that, the data looks like:

```
   ID Year Variable_of_Interest Solution
1   a 2000                    0       -5
2   a 2001                    0       -4
3   a 2002                    0       -3
4   a 2003                    0       -2
5   a 2004                    0       -1
6   a 2005                    1        0
7   a 2006                    1        1
8   a 2007                    1        2
9   a 2008                    1        3
10  a 2009                    1        4
11  b 2000                    0       -3
12  b 2001                    0       -2
13  b 2002                    0       -1
14  b 2003                    1        0
15  b 2004                    1        1
16  b 2005                    1        2
17  b 2006                    0       -1
18  b 2007                    1        0
19  b 2008                    1        1
20  b 2009                    1        2
21  c 2000                    0       -6
22  c 2001                    0       -5
23  c 2002                    0       -4
24  c 2003                    0       -3
25  c 2004                    0       -2
26  c 2005                    0       -1
27  c 2006                    1        0
28  c 2007                    1        1
29  c 2008                    1        2
30  c 2009                    0       NA
31  d 2000                    0       -2
32  d 2001                    0       -1
33  d 2002                    1        0
34  d 2003                    1        1
35  d 2004                    0       -1
36  d 2005                    1        0
37  d 2006                    1        1
38  d 2007                    1        2
39  d 2008                    1        3
40  d 2009                    1        4
```

Here is the replication code:

```
ID <- c(rep("a",10), rep("b", 10), rep("c", 10), rep("d", 10)); length(ID)
Year <- rep(seq(2000,2009, 1), 4)
Variable_of_Interest <- c(rep(0,5), rep(1, 5), 
                         rep(0,3), rep(1, 3), rep(0, 1), rep(1, 3),
                         rep(0,6), rep(1, 3), rep(0, 1),
                         rep(0,2), rep(1, 2), rep(0,1), rep(1,5))


data.frame(ID, Year, Variable_of_Interest)
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` option:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, idx = cumsum(Variable_of_Interest != lag(Variable_of_Interest, default = first(Variable_of_Interest)))) %>%
  mutate(Solution = case_when(Variable_of_Interest == 0 ~ rev(-1:(-n())), Variable_of_Interest == 1 ~ 0:(n() - 1))) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Solution = replace(Solution, idx == max(idx) & Variable_of_Interest == 0, NA)) %>%
  select(-idx)
```

Output:

```
   ID Year Variable_of_Interest idx Solution
1   a 2000                    0   0       -5
2   a 2001                    0   0       -4
3   a 2002                    0   0       -3
4   a 2003                    0   0       -2
5   a 2004                    0   0       -1
6   a 2005                    1   1        0
7   a 2006                    1   1        1
8   a 2007                    1   1        2
9   a 2008                    1   1        3
10  a 2009                    1   1        4
11  b 2000                    0   2       -3
12  b 2001                    0   2       -2
13  b 2002                    0   2       -1
14  b 2003                    1   3        0
15  b 2004                    1   3        1
16  b 2005                    1   3        2
17  b 2006                    0   4       -1
18  b 2007                    1   5        0
19  b 2008                    1   5        1
20  b 2009                    1   5        2
21  c 2000                    0   6       -6
22  c 2001                    0   6       -5
23  c 2002                    0   6       -4
24  c 2003                    0   6       -3
25  c 2004                    0   6       -2
26  c 2005                    0   6       -1
27  c 2006                    1   7        0
28  c 2007                    1   7        1
29  c 2008                    1   7        2
30  c 2009                    0   8       NA
31  d 2000                    0   8       -2
32  d 2001                    0   8       -1
33  d 2002                    1   9        0
34  d 2003                    1   9        1
35  d 2004                    0  10       -1
36  d 2005                    1  11        0
37  d 2006                    1  11        1
38  d 2007                    1  11        2
39  d 2008                    1  11        3
40  d 2009                    1  11        4
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option using `data.table`:

```
#identify runs
setDT(DF)[, ri := rleid(voi)]

#generate the desired output depending on whether VOI is 1 or 0
DF[, soln := if (voi[1L]==1L) seq.int(.N) - 1L else -rev(seq.int(.N)), .(ID, ri)]

#replace trailing 0 with NA
DF[, soln := if(voi[.N]==0L) replace(soln, ri==ri[.N], NA_integer_) else soln, ID]
```

data:

```
ID <- c(rep("a",10), rep("b", 10), rep("c", 10), rep("d", 10)); length(ID)
Year <- rep(seq(2000,2009, 1), 4)
Variable_of_Interest <- c(rep(0,5), rep(1, 5), 
    rep(0,3), rep(1, 3), rep(0, 1), rep(1, 3),
    rep(0,6), rep(1, 3), rep(0, 1),
    rep(0,2), rep(1, 2), rep(0,1), rep(1,5))
DF <- data.frame(ID, Year, voi=Variable_of_Interest)
```